# Recursive types and arrays

Tags: rust

Okay, so I am just starting learn a little bit of Rust and I am running to a pretty simple problem. I have a recursive type like this:

```
struct Tree {
    root : i32,
    children : Box<[Option<Tree> ; 100]>
}
```

Later, when I was trying to initialize Tree

```
hex.rs:30:29: 30:40 error: the trait `core::marker::Copy` is not implemented for the type `Tree` [E0277]
hex.rs:30         children : Box::new([None; 100])
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

So, I added

```
#[derive(Copy)]
```

before the struct definition, but I got this error:

```
hex.rs:8:10: 8:14 error: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type; field `children` does not implement `Copy` [E0204]
hex.rs:8 #[derive(Copy)]
                  ^~~~
note: in expansion of #[derive]
hex.rs:8:1: 8:16 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I am not entirely sure where to go from here. Is there an easy way to derive traits for recursive data types?

Comment: It’s just `[None; 100]` that you can’t write; `[None, None, None, None, …]` would work fine. But semantically I imagine `Vec<Tree>` is more what you want.

Comment: Right, I tried that and it worked, but that feels wrong for so many reasons. Vec<Tree> works for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`Box`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) doesn't support [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). Copy states:

> Types that can be copied by simply copying bits

However, a `Box` contains pointers to memory, and that memory will not be copied when you just copy the bits of the pointer.

When you are constructing your array, Rust only knows that you are going to put an `Option` in there. There isn't a way to have a enum only half-implement a trait.

Do you need to use a fixed-size array? Perhaps this would work better:

```
struct Tree {
    root : i32,
    children : Vec<Tree>
}
```

Your constructor can then use [`Vec::with_capacity`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity):

```
impl Tree {
    fn new(root: i32) -> Tree {
        Tree { root: root, children: Vec::with_capacity(100) }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Box` is redundant because `Vec` already adds a layer of indirection.

Comment: A fixed size array would suit my needs much better.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev great point! Mostly due to my naïve translation. :-)

Comment: @Shepmaster is it possible to preallocate a specific amount of space with a Vec?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you won't be able to use static arrays and recursive types like that without `unsafe`. The reason is that array initializers require the array element type to be `Copy` because they initialize all elements with bytewise copies of the initial element, and your type can't be `Copy` because it contains `Box`, which is the only safe way to allow recursive types in Rust (well, there are also `Vec` and other similar containers, but they also need a heap allocation).

If you are not afraid of allocations, you can just as well use `Vec`:

```
struct Tree {
    root: i32,
    children: Vec<Tree>
}
```

Then the initialization could look like

```
Tree {
    root: 0,
    children: vec![]
}
```

Comment: But my initial element is a None. Why does it even need the `Copy` instance for Tree?

Comment: It doesn't matter - your type is not `Copy`, hence `Option<Tree>` is not `Copy` as well. I suspect it *might* be possible to special-case null-argument enum variants for them to be usable in such situations, but I think that this is a rare case, so no one bothered yet. Maybe when we get generic literals, it will change.